# Edit comment link in flag queue disappears when editing a post

Tags: bug, status-declined, moderator-tools, comment-edits, internet-explorer-8

The "edit" link to edit flagged comments in the flag queue disappears after clicking the "edit" link for a question/answer.

[image]

This happens whether clicking edit on a flagged post or on the post associated with a flagged comment, and happens to all flagged comments listed on the page. Saving/cancelling the edit does not correct the issue.

Note that the link still works even though it's not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking as declined -- we don't support visual glitches for this version of IE.